# Is the following inequality correct?

Tags: matrices, inequality, quadratic-forms, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to understand whether the following inequality is correct. Let $Y,X$ be random variables and $f(X)$, $n\times 1$-dimensional function of $X$. It is claimed that
$$\begin{aligned}
& a'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}A'B^{-1}\mathbb{E}[Yf(X)f(X)']B^{-1}A(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}a \\
& \geq \inf_x\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]\|a'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}A'B^{-1/2}\|,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $A,B$ are matrices and $a$ is a vector of compatible dimensions (deterministic), $\mathbb{E}[f(X)f(X)']=B$ is positive definite and $A$ is full-column rank.

How to see that this inequality is correct?

Comment: There is some easy cancellation to begin with...

Comment: Are they still there, after the correction of typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$g(x)=\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)\\
c=\inf_x g(x)\\
h^2(x)=g(x)-c$$
Then, from the right-hand side,
$$||a'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}A'B^{-1/2}||=
a'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}A'B^{-1}A'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}a\\
=a'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}A'B^{-1}BB^{-1}A'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}a\\
=a'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}A'B^{-1}\mathbb{E}(f(X)f'(X))B^{-1}A'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}a$$
So the difference between the two sides is 
$$a'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}A'B^{-1}\mathbb{E}(f(X)h(X)h(X)f'(X))B^{-1}A'(A'B^{-1}A)^{-1}a\\
=\mathbb{E}(||a'(A'B^{-1}A^{-1}A'B^{-1}f(X)h(X)||)\geq0$$